Batch file argument that may be passed as integer
I try to write a batch script comparing the input with 2 integers and if it's in their range, the value is assigned to a variable. The other string parameters can be also passed as an argument so I don't know which argument is the one I'm looking for.
I'm trying sth like this:
SET MIN=20
SET MAX=79
if not "%~1"=="" (
    if %2 leq %MAX% if %2 geq %MIN% set VAR=%2
    )
if not "%~2"=="" (
    if %2 leq %MAX% if %2 geq %MIN% set VAR=%2
    )
if not "%~3"=="" (
    if %3 leq %MAX% if %3 geq %MIN% set VAR=%3
    )

The problem is when I pass only 2 arguments to the script the 3rd condition will crash with a message:

79 was unexpected at this time.

It looks like the expression inside the condition is evaluated by the script and I'm not sure how I can solve this.
Sth like this works but I don't like it because it looks terrible:
if not "%~2"=="" (set TMP_VAR=%2) else (set TMP_VAR=99999)  
if %TMP_VAR% leq %MAX% if %TMP_VAR% geq %MIN% set VAR=%TMP_VAR%


Thank you @Compo. It's approach I've decided to use.

If you can guarantee a maximum of only one argument in range, (and you aren't passing crazy arguments), then you can probably just do it like this:
For %%G In (%*) Do If 1%%~G GEq 1%MIN% If 1%%~G LEq 1%MAX% Set "VAR=%%~G"

This idea utilises %*, which represents all arguments. The For loop passes each argument one at a time through to the Do portion which performs the range comparison on them, and defines the VAR variable with the content of the last comparison match.

The issue is that when a statement if…(…) or if…(…) else (…) is parsed, the entire statement must be syntactically correct to be executed, using the current value of any variables involved.
So, if %3 is missing, then the statement becomes, when parsed :
if not ""=="" (if leq 79 if geq 20 set VAR=)
So the parser sees if leq 79, figures that 79 is not a comparison-operator, hence the statement is syntactically incorrect, so reports and stops.
Note that only the syntax is considered, so the fact that not ""=="" would cause the statement not to be executed is not relevant.
So - how to fix?
How about
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET /a max=79
SET /a min=20
set /a var1=%~1 2>nul
set /a var2=%~2 2>nul
set /a var3=%~3 2>nul

set "error="

CALL :VERIFY var1 "%var1%" "%~1"
CALL :VERIFY var2 "%var2%" "%~2"
CALL :VERIFY var3 "%var3%" "%~3"

SET err
SET var
GOTO :eof

:VERIFY

if NOT defined %1 set "error=%error% %1 not defined"&GOTO :eof
:: %1 is a defined variable
if %2 neq %3 set "error=%error% %1 not numeric"&GOTO :eof
IF %~2 gtr %MAX% set "error=%error% %1 too big"&GOTO :eof
IF %~2 lss %MIN% set "error=%error% %1 too small"&GOTO :eof

GOTO :eof

set /a sets a variable in arithmetic mode. The 2>nul suppresses error messages like "Missing operand."
Establish an empty variable called error.
Execute the verify subroutine, passing the name, quoted value and quoted source value of the variable being verified.
The subroutine checks that the variable has been defined, generating an error if not.
Then matches the value assigned to the variable (%2) against the value specified as the program parameter (%3). If these are different, then the program has been supplied wit a non-numeric parameter (like junk) or a valid non-decimal string (like 0xa3, which evaluates to 163 - and the strings 0xa3 & 163 differ)
Then against the limits.
If all tests pass, then if defined error will be FALSE.
set err/set var are simply quick methods to display the value(s) of variables that start err/var

If the parameters consists in just two numbers and an optional string at any position, then this crazy method can solve this problem in a very simple way:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A MIN=20, MAX=79

set "values=%*"
set "formula=VAR+=val*((((MIN-val)*(val-MAX))>>31)+1)"
set /A "VAR=0,val=!values: =,%formula%,val=!,%formula%"
echo VAR=%VAR%

The innermost part of the formula: (MIN-val)*(val-MAX) gives a positive or zero result if the value is in range (negative otherwise) as described at this site. The ( ... )>>31 part gives 0 if the value is in range and -1 otherwise, so val*(( ... )+1) is the same value if it is in range and zero otherwise.
At beginning the parameters are stored in values variable. The val=!values: =,%formula%,val=!,%formula% expansion inserts the previous formula after each given parameter using the method described here, so the same calculation is performed via the set /A command over each parameter. The VAR variable collects all intermediate results, so the final result is the value of the parameter that is in range. If more than one parameter is in range, the VAR variable will contain the sum of all of them although this point can be fixed in a very simple way in order to gest just one parameter in range: the first one. The set /A command replaces by zero any string parameter.
An interesting point of this method is that it will correctly work no matter the number of parameters, so the exact same method could be applied to any number of parameters with no modification.

@echo off && setlocal

set "_var="
set /a "_min=20, _max=79"
     
( echo/%~1 & echo/%~2 & echo/%~3 ) | findstr [2-7][0-9] | find /v /c "" | findstr /be [1-3] >nul || (
  echo/Missing argument ^(integer in the range %_min%~%_max% ^) & goto :eof
)

for /f usebackq %%G in (`" ( @for %%i in ( %* ) do @echo/%%~i ) | sort /uniq /r "`
    ) do echo/_Arg=%%G & if 1%%~G leq 1%_max% if 1%%~G geq 1%_min% ( call set "_var=%%~G" & goto %:^))
        
%:^)
set _ | find "_var"

rem :: your code continue here ::

endlocal


Define variables and set the range of valid integers (_min to _max).
Checks if at least one integer argument is passed and if it is in the range 20 to 79.
Display an error and exit if no argument matches an element within the defined range.
If no valid argument is found, it displays an error message for a missing integer argument and exits.
Processes the arguments by sorting them and removing duplicate numbers/arguments
If any exist in the range, the largest integer valid within the specified range is stored in your variable _var.
Finally, the value of _var is displayed and the script continues from the point marked "Your code continues here".
If you want to get the smallest integer passed as an argument, simply remove the /r flag from the sort command.


Alternative:

@echo off && setlocal

set "_var=" && set /a "_min=20, _max=79"

( for /f usebackq %%G in (`" 2>nul ( for %%i in (%*) do @echo/%%i ) | findstr [2-7][0-9] "`
    ) do if 1%%~G leq 1%_max% if 1%%~G geq 1%_min% set "_var=%%~G" 
) 2>nul || echo/No valid integer argument was provided.

if defined _var set _ | find "_var"
rem :: your code continue here ::
endlocal

